# auto-complete based on model's multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

in my form for creating a new `Event`, I made a auto-complete field for `Venue` based on [this railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised?autoplay=true). but this way it only works when entering a venue name. how to make the same field also work for when entering an address, kind of how it is on GoogleMaps?

models/event.rb

```
  def find_venue
    venue.try(:name)
  end

  def find_venue=(name)
    self.venue = Venue.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

javascripts/events.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#event_find_venue').autocomplete
    source: $('#event_find_venue').data('autocomplete-source')
```

new.html.erb:

```
  <%= f.text_field :find_venue, data: {autocomplete_source: Venue.order(:name).map(&:name)} %>
```

venues_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @venues = Venue.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
    render json: @venues.map(&:name)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use multiple OR conditions to match each attribute:

```
Venue.order(:name).where("name like ? OR address like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%", "%#{params[:address]}%")
```

You may also want to consider using `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` if you're not concerned with case sensitivity.

Comment: not working. are you sure that's all that needs to be changed? also, is `"%#{params[:address]}%"` necessary in this case? it seem like `render json: @venues.map(&:address)` would also need to be inside the controller.